# How to redirext all adresses to directories to default file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to prevent to access directory content to deny possibility to see directories content and redirect all request of directory access to default file i.e. index.html

i.e.:

```
excample.com/projects/list.html - should be accessed in normal mode
excample.com/projects/ - should redirect to index.html to not allow user to see content 
excample.com/parts/ - the same as above
excample.com/parts/machines/ - the same as above
excample.com/parts/machines/outofproduction.html - should open
```

Are there also another methods how to protect website from view directories?

Comment: `DirectoryIndex index.html` and `Options -Indexes` should take care of that.

Comment: ...although this is the default behaviour, so I'm wondering if there is some other requirement? If there is always a directory index document in the requested directory (as implied by the example) then `Options -Indexes` is redundant.